# For Rudin 1.15, why can't B or C be both $0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Question: Under what conditions does equality hold in the Schwarz inequality?

---

Below is the section in the textbook that I'm working on. I understand that I want $Ba_j - Cb_j = 0$ in order to get equality and, in a geometric interpretation, I can see why $a$ and $b$ would be linearly dependent (since that above equation is equivalent to $Ba_j = Cb_j$) but I don't understand how to get a specific relationship of $B$ and $C$ or what the restrictions are.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since we have$$\sum_{j=1}^n|Ba_j-Cb_j|^2=B\left(AB-|C|^2\right),$$we have the equality $AB=|C|^2$ if and only if $|Ba_j-Cb_j|=0$ for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. But, since we are assuming that $B\ne0$, this means that $a_j=\frac CBb_j$ for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. In other words,$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\frac CB(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n).$$

Comment: That's basically what I think but it seems far too simple.

Comment: Have you noticed any mistake in my answer?

Comment: I think your answer is correct (in fact, it's very similar to my equivalent equation $Ba_j = C b_j$)